# Collapsed list showing all items on expand webpart SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, classic-experience, list-webpart

I am using a classic site on SharePoint online. I have a list webpart on a classic page. I have the items grouped by status, and set to collapsed. When I click open one of the groups, it ends up showing all the items instead of just those in the group.

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your list view is corrupted and not showing the following groups when the first one is clicked on. How many records do you have in this list? Can you reproduce this issue on all the groups?

You can navigate back to the list and see if the list itself has the same issue. If yes, reconfigure the **group by** feature. If not, re-add this web part to your page.

Ps. I think I have temporarily reproduced this issue by switching the **Toolbar Type** via *Edit Web Part > List Views*, but it eventually went away. Try switching this option at your end and see if it fixes the issue.